# detecting scroll direction, only the first conditional triggers

Tags: jquery

I want to detect if the user is scrolling up or down, if up I want to add a class of `fixed` to the header and if down, remove it.

With the following code the `fixed` class gets assigned only if the user is scrolling up, and does not change if the user scrolls down again (which is fine):

```
                var lastScrollTop = 0;
                $(window).scroll(function(event) {

                    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

                    if (st > lastScrollTop){
                    } else {
                        $('header.banner').addClass('fixed');

                    }

                    lastScrollTop = st;

                    if (st === 0) {
                        $('header.banner').removeClass('fixed');
                    }

                });
```

But now I want to remove the `fixed` class when the user scrolls down again, and with the following code the `fixed` class does not get added at all , here's the relevant updated part of code:

```
                    if (st > lastScrollTop){
                        $('header.banner').removeClass('fixed');
                    } else {
                        $('header.banner').addClass('fixed');

                    }
```

Why does it not remove class `fixed` when scrolling down but ADD `fixed` when scrolling up?

Comment: do you want your header banner to be always visible on top. If so, why don't you give it position fixed from the start instead of adding/removing class on scroll ?

Comment: No I do not as I clearly stated in the Q.